# Read Parameters out of icalendar file with JS

Tags: javascript, regex, icalendar

I'd like to read several parameters out of an iCalendar file with JavaScript.

The file input looks like:

> BEGIN:VEVENT DTSTART:20121127T190000Z DTEND:20121127T210000Z DTSTAMP:20121130T185808Z UID:q4sbrtajjol1hlpiijpho5jac0@google.com CREATED:20121102T191519Z DESCRIPTION:1. Bundesliga\, 14. Spieltag \n\nhttp://www.fussball-spielplan. info LAST-MODIFIED:20121127T211459Z LOCATION:Commerzbank-Arena\, Frankfurt SEQUENCE:10 STATUS:CONFIRMED SUMMARY:Eintracht Frankfurt - 1. FSV Mainz 05 (1:3) TRANSP:TRANSPARENT END:VEVENT

The parameter tags are:

```
DTSTART:
DTEND:
DTSTAMP:
UID:
CREATED:
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:
LOCATION:
STATUS:
SUMMARY:
TRANSP:
```

I want to read the values behind these parameters.
The length of the values are mostly variable.

Using a `RegExp` is quite hard as I currently don't know what to set as a delimiter.
`"\n"` doesn't work as all text parts are separated by a space.
But if I use the space delimiter `"\s"` it will separate after each word, which is not the wanted result especially for the parameter `DESCRIPTION:` with a longer text included.

My source code looks currently like this:

```
file_reader.onload = function (evt) {
document.getElementById("filedrag").textContent = evt.target.result;

Output(
    "<p>File information: <strong>" + file.name +
    "</strong> type: <strong>" + file.type +
    "</strong> size: <strong>" + file.size +
    "</strong> bytes</p>");

var regexp = new RegExp("/DTSTART:(.*?)\s/", "g"); 
var file_content = evt.target.result;
var match, matches = [];

while ((match = regexp.exec(file_content)) != null) {
    matches.push(match.index);
}

alert(matches);
}
```

Any ideas, how I can achieve my idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have

```
var regexp = new RegExp("/DTSTART:(.*?)\s/", "g");
```

but the regular expression delimiter `/` is not required when passing a string to the `RegExp` constructor - it will be interpreted as a character to be matched. Also, as its a string any special RegExp characters need to be double escaped, so `\s` should be `\\s`.

Here is one way of getting the values for each specified tag:

```
var match,
    matches = [],
    tags = 'DTSTART|DTEND|DTSTAMP|UID|CREATED|DESCRIPTION|' +
           'LAST-MODIFIED|LOCATION|STATUS|SUMMARY|TRANSP',
    regexp = new RegExp( '(?:' +  tags + '):([\\s\\S]*?)(?=\\s+(?:' +
                                  tags + '|SEQUENCE|END):)', 'g' );   

while ( match = regexp.exec( file_content ) ) {
    matches.push( match[1] );
}
```

If you want to retrieve each tag:value pair, change `match[1]` to `match[0]`.

The above assumes that there is at least one space or newline character before each tag.
It also assumes that a space followed by a tag name followed by a `:` does not appear in any tag's value.

`[\\s\\S]` is used instead of `.` so that newline characters can be included in a tag's value.

The above does not capture the value of the `SEQUENCE` tag as it was not specified in the list.
If you want to capture it, just add it to `tags` and remove it from `regexp` so `'|SEQUENCE|END):)'` becomes `'|END):)'`.

Alternatively:

```
var m,
    params = {},
    rex = /([A-Z-]+):([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+[A-Z-]+:|$)/g;   

while ( m = rex.exec( file_content ) ) {
    params[ m[1] ] = m[2];
}

console.log( params["DTSTART"] );    // 20121127T190000Z
```

Comment: brilliant, works like a charm! a question in addition: If I would like to get the DTSTART value in order to use it for an SQL statement, how would I extend the while condition?

Comment: @Daniel. The `DTSTART` value will be the first item of the array, i.e. `matches[0]`.

Comment: @Daniel. I've added an alternative version which makes it easier to get each desired parameter.

Comment: Selecting values of the array this way would require the order of the tags to always be the same. Furthermore it would be necessary for each tag to always exist. 
In my case the "BEGIN" and "END" tag are containers for the other tags. There might be multiple "BEGIN" and "END" containers in one file. The tags within this container might be in random order, some might be there or might be missing.
So I guess I would need to check for each container if the required tag exists or not.
Would it be possible to add one more alternative?

Comment: @Daniel. The version I added doesn't require that the order of the tags be the same or for each tag to always exist. If there are multiple containers you could first match the container from BEGIN to END and then get the keys-value pairs for each as shown above.

Comment: I'd need the same RegEx now in my php source-code.
How would the RegEx look like in php?

Answer (score 1):

```
var params={};
fileContent.replace(/([\w-]+):([^:]+)\s/g,function($0,$1,$2){params[$1]=$2;});
```

The above regex assumes that:

- your parameters are single words (no space) followed by a colon `([\w-]+):`
- the values don't contain colons `([^:]+)`

If your values (for example the DESCRIPTION text) can contain colons, then you'll need to be more specific about the parameters (cf. @MikeM's answer).

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zhsLJ/

Comment: I like this use of replace so +1 from me, but it doesn't handle `SUMMARY` or `LAST-MODIFIED` correctly. How about `/([A-Z-]+):([\s\S]*?)(?=\s[A-Z-]+:|$)/g`.

Comment: @MikeM thx for the comment. I have corrected the regex to accept a dash. As for SUMMARY, the issue is that the value contains a colon, so - as I say in the answer - in this case my regex is not specific enough and yours will work better.